# Pointer alternative in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pointers

I need an alternative for a C/C++-like pointer in C#, so that I can store the reference of a variable passed in a constructor. I want my local pointer to change its value every time the references value changes. Just like a pointer. But I don't want to use the real pointers in C# because they are unsafe. Is there a workaround?

```
    class A
    {
        public Int32 X = 10;
    }

    class B
    {
        public B(Int32 x)
        {
            Y = x;
        }

        public Int32 Y { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B(a.X);

        Console.WriteLine(b.Y); // 10
        a.X = 11;
        Console.WriteLine(b.Y); // 10, but I want it to be 11
    }
```

Comment: You can solve the issue by passing a reference to `a` instead of an `int`, then you can do `public int Y => a.X`.

Comment: The `x` value is passed by value onto the ctor. You can use `ref` keyword in the ctor of B to have your ctor argument passed by reference and not by value. In any case, if you're going to pass an argument of `Bitmap` type, I don't see the problem in just having the program as it stands now, as `Bitmap` is a reference type, so you already have your refencence (and pointer).

Comment: Everything that doesn't inherit from `ValueType` is a pointer

Comment: @HimBromBeere totally agree with you on that first correction - pedantic point, though: "However it is passed by reference" - no, the value *is* a reference, passed by value

Comment: _I need...But I don't want_ Once you have learned C# basics these misguided emotions and ideas will go away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forget Pointers and start thinking in C# while coding in C# :D

I'd do something like this:

```
public interface IXProvider
{
     int X {get;}
}

class A : IXProvider
{
    public int X {get; set;} = 10;
}

class B
{
    public B(IXProvider x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }

    private readonly IXProvider _x;
    public int Y => _x.X;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B(a);

    Console.WriteLine(b.Y); // 10
    a.X = 11;
    Console.WriteLine(b.Y); // 11
}
```

Example with Bitmap: (For simplicity, assume "SomeBitmap" and "AnotherBitmap" to be actual Bitmaps)

```
public interface IBitmapProvider
{
     Bitmap X {get;}
}

class A : IBitmapProvider
{
    public Bitmap X {get; set;} = SomeBitmap;
}

class B
{
    public B(IBitmapProvider x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }

    private readonly IBitmapProvider _x;
    public Bitmap Y => _x.X;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B(a);

    Console.WriteLine(b.Y); // SomeBitmap
    a.X = AnotherBitmap;
    Console.WriteLine(b.Y); // AnotherBitmap
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are essentially 3 types of references in .NET

1. object references (i.e. a local/param/field of type `A`, where `A` is a reference-type - a `class`, `interface`, `delegate`, etc)
2. unmanaged pointers  (i.e. a local/param/field of type `Foo*`)
3. managed pointers (i.e. a local/param of type `ref Foo`)

You (quite wisely) say you don't want to use "2", and "3" can *only* be used on the stack (as local variables or parameters), so that leaves "1", which is possible. For example, by passing in an `A` object instance instead of an `int`. See @Fildor's answer for a walkthrough of this.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is to wrap your value type into a reference type. Consider this:

```
object o1 = new object();
object o2 = o1;
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
class Obj {
    public int Val;
}

void Main() {
    Obj o1 = new Obj();
    o1.Val = 5;
    Obj o2 = o1;
    o2.Val = 8;
//o1.Val is 8 now
}
```

Comment: it really isn't obvious to me what the first example (with `o1`/`o2`) is meant to be showing in this context

Answer (score 1):

there´s a huge difference between value-tpes such as `int` and reference-typpes such as `MyClass`. As you´re actually interested in `BitMap` which **is** a referencetype, you don´t need to do any pointer-logic. The variable already **is** a reference. Changing its state e.g. by modifying any of its public properties will be reflected in all other references anyway.

So when your class `A` has a variable of type `Bitmap` you can use that one from any other code as well (assuming you can *access* that member, e.g. when it is `private` you surely cannot).

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a.Image); // this will just reference the bitmap instead of copying it
b.Image.Modify(); // this will also be reflected in a.x
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with C#, so I can't provide a working answer but pointers definitely exist in C#.

`int* ptr = &a`

Take a look at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types

Comment: You need to use unsafe for this.

Comment: well yes, but in C# you need to declare this as 'unsafe' and I would like to bypass that

Comment: Yes this exists, but you need to be *really, really careful* when using `unsafe` code. In this case, OP wants to store it as a field. That is a recipe for disaster if the thing you're talking about is an "interior pointer" (i.e. something you needed to use `fixed` to obtain), because the value *should be considered dead* the moment that the `fixed` block ends, because at that point the GC is allowed to *move the original object* (and your unmanaged pointer won't get updated). Corollary: guiding people to using an advanced and nuanced language feature without the warnings: can be unhelpful

Answer (score 0):

C# makes a distinction between *value types* and *reference types*. Value types (structs and primitive types, except `string`<sup>1</sup>) are passed around by value (a copy is made), while reference types (classes) are essentially fancy pointers. (BTW, in an IDE, if you hover your mouse over a variable, it will tell you if it's a class or a struct).

So, keeping that in mind, this is what your code does:

```
class A       // reference type
{
    public Int32 X = 10;     // with a value type field
}

class B       // reference type
{
    // The ctor takes in a value type parameter; a copy of the 
    // value is passed in (pretty much like in C++)
    public B(Int32 x)
    {
        Y = x;       // this now contains its own copy
    }

    // value type PROPERTY -- see below
    public Int32 Y { get; set; }
}
```

So, in your main method, when you do

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a.X);
```

b.Y has no connection to a.X because the constructor gets a copy of a.X as soon as a.X is evaluated.

The simplest thing you can do is to have the constructor of B accept a parameter of type A instead, and then store a reference to A internally:

```
class B
{
    private A _a;
    
    public B(A a)    // a is passed in by reference
    {
        _a = a;       
    }

    public Int32 Y { 
        get => _a.X; 
        set => _a.X = value; 
    }     
}
```

Now when you do

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);
```

the `a` refers to the same object both inside and outside of `b`. Changing `a.X` will affect the result of invoking `b.Y`.

You can also expose `a` directly:

```
class B
{
    public B(A a)
    {
        A = a;
    }

    public A A { get; set; }
}
```

Then in main():

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);

Console.WriteLine(b.A.X);   // 10
a.X = 11;
Console.WriteLine(b.A.X);   // 11
```

### A note about properties

You should be aware of the difference between fields and properties. Fields are data members, just like in C++. A *property* is just some syntactic sugar for a get/set method pair that's generated behind the scenes by the compiler. It's roughly equivalent to something like this:

```
class B
{
    private A _a;
    
    public B(A a)
    {
        _a = a;       
    }

    public A GetA() { 
        return _a; 
    }     

    public void SetA(A value) { 
        _a = value;
    }      
}
```

In this case, since A is a reference type, it's returned by reference from the getter. But suppose now that A was declared to be a struct (a value type). Then the getter would return a copy. This sometimes causes a problem that's not obvious to C# beginners.

```
struct A       // value type
{
    public Int32 X;     // with a value type field
    public A(Int32 x) { X = x; }
}
```

If A is a struct, and you try to do

`b.A.X = 11;`

you'll get a compiler error: "Cannot modify the return value of 'b.A.X' because it is not a variable".

The reason is because `b.A` returns a copy, so if you changed `X` on it, the change would be lost after that line. You have to replace the entire `A` instance instead:

```
A a = new A(10);   // struct
B b = new B(a);    // class containing a struct


Console.WriteLine(b.A.X);   // 10

a.X = 11;
Console.WriteLine(b.A.X);   // 10  - because A is a value type now

b.A = new A(11);            // setting a property on B works as expected,
                            // but you can't do b.A.X = 11

Console.WriteLine(b.A.X);   // 11
```

P.S. In C#, you would typically write `int` instead of `Int32`.

---

<sup>1</sup> `string` is a reference type, however, it's *immutable* (all operations that "modify" strings return separate `string` instances).